# Syntax error in angularjs while Data binding

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

browserLink:37 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input#{role}(…)

//template

```
<div ng-repeat="role in roles">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{role}}" value="{{role}}" ng-model="role" ng -checked="getCheckedTrue[{{role}}]" />
    {{role}}
</div>
```

//js

```
$scope.roles = [
   'Dentist',
   'HeartSurgeon',
   'Cance'
];

$scope.getCheckedTrue = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Doctor/getType?searchString=' + $scope.role,
    }).then(function successCallback(responce) {
        $scope.Doctors = responce.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
    });
};`
```

//Controller

```
    public JsonResult getType(string searchString)

    {

        var Doctor = db.DocMaster.Where(f =>
      f.DocType.StartsWith(searchString)).ToList();
        var JsonResult = Json(Doctor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        JsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

        return JsonResult;

    }
```

Comment: post the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //For getting the all records from database. Controller
 //c# controller
    public JsonResult get(string searchString)
     {
        var Doctor = db.DocMaster.Where(f =>
      f.DocType.StartsWith(searchString)).ToList();
        var JsonResult = Json(Doctor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        JsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return JsonResult;
    }
```

//View

```
                <div ng-repeat="(typeKey, typeVal) in roles">
                    <div ng-repeat="value in typeVal">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   ng-model="x"
                                   ng-change="setOutput(typeKey, $index, value)">{{value}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

//angular-controller

```
 $scope.outputs = {};
$scope.setOutput = function (typeKey, $index, value) {
    $scope.Doctors = {};
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Doctor/get?searchString='+value,
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log(response);
        $scope.Doctors = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        alert("Error : " + response.data.ExceptionMessage);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference the input by name instead of input

Answer (score 0):

I believe ng-checked="getCheckedTrue[{{role}}]" should in fact be ng-checked="getCheckedTrue[role]"

Answer (score 0):

getCheckedTrue is function and you are using it as an array.

so, instead of getCheckedTrue[{{role}}] it should be getCheckedTrue({{role}})

Also, the role value is string so you better to use getCheckedTrue('{{role}}')